# Is it possible to have a php file in apache operate without an extension?

Tags: php, apache-config

I have a file

```
http://www.www.com/somefile.php
```

I would like to be able to get to the same file by going to

```
http://www.www.com/somefile
```

But I still need

```
http://www.www.com/directory
```

to open the file

```
http://www.www.com/directory/index.php
```

if, in fact, directory is a directory.

This is a typical LAMP setup with Red Hat and Apache.

Is that possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An apache rewrite rule will do this for you.  The only limitation is you can't have a file named "somefile.php" and a directory named "somefile" (though you can still have directories.

Here's an example rule that supports multiple filenames (just put in in your .htaccess file).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(somefile1|somefile2|somefile3) $1.php
```

Will change /somefile1 to /somefile1.php, /somefile2 to /somefile2.php, and /somefile3 to /somefile3.php.

Comment: ^ This.  Don't rename your file, just change how Apache matches URLs to filenames.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Apache's ForceType.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the need of  file extensions on the url globally on your site, you can also add the following to your `.htaccess`:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

This will enable [Content Negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html). But if you want to match only certain files and/or urls, stick with [SoapBox's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204316/is-it-possible-to-have-a-php-file-in-apache-operate-without-an-extension/2204334#2204334) instead.